# How to set bean values for JSF page

Tags: java, jsf, javabeans

I have a JSF page(page 1) which returns values from another JSF page (page 2) and values are passed to backing bean properly. In fact values are passed to bean in the action method of page 2.
Action method closes page 2 and refreshes page 1.

My question is which event should I set the bean values for page 1 after getting values from page 1, should I do that in same action method for closing page 2? when I did this I cannot see anything displayed in page 1.

I am using JSF 1.1

Any help is highly appreciated.